# How to display the checked radio button label in the next activity?

Tags: java, android

```
int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioButton2 = findViewById(radioId);
textView1.setText(radioButton2.getText() + " > ");
```

I want to display the label of checked radio button in the next activity like this -----> Android Developers > Docs > Guiders

Please help me.

Next, how can I display the label of checked radio button
(first activity) in the third activity ?

Comment: What Do You Want Actually, Do You Want To Pass The Label Of The CheckBox Who Is Checked To The Next Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways that's depend on your need:

1. Using Intent Data

You can put that text as extra into your intent that starting next activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("CheckedRadioText", radioButton2.getText());
startActivity(i);
```

And get extra at next activity's onCreate method like below:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String text = i.getStringExtra("CheckedRadioText");
myTextView.setText(text);
```

2. You can set radio button's text to a static string and access it from next activity easily (personally, not recommended).
3. If this radio button is something like setting selection that you need to save this. Then you can save that text to a sharedPreference. There are several tutorials available for this approach.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much for that solution. It worked !